# Realize a homomorphism $\mathcal{C}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ as an evaluation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. It is well-known that every homomorphism $F : \mathcal{C}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ is the evaluation $f \mapsto f(x)$ at some point $x \in X$. The usual proof is not really constructive, but for $X=[0,1]$ there is a constructive one. For details see my [crosspost](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97603/realizing-a-homomorphism-mathcalcx-to-mathbbr-as-an-evaluation) on math.SE. Feel free to replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$.

**Question.** Is there an explicit example of $X$ and $F : \mathcal{C}(X) \to \mathbb{R}$ as above such that 1) syntactically $F$ is not defined as an evaluation, 2) one does not see directly that $F$ is an evaluation, 3) some computation has to be done to find the point $x \in X$ such that $F$ is the evaluation at $x$?

Background: Gelfand duality states that the adjunction between $\mathrm{Spec}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is actually an equivalence, which means that A) for every compact Hausdorff space $X$ the unit $X \to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{C}(X))$ is an isomorphism and B) for every commutative unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ the counit $A \to \mathcal{C}(\mathrm{Spec}(A))$ is an isomorphism. There are many important applications for B), for example the existence of the functional calculus, but I don't know of any specific application for A) (as a result independent from this duality). It would be nice to have some computational example which shows the relevance of A). Actually I'm after another duality, where A) is already proven but its significance is unclear.

Comment: The classical statement of Gelfand-Neumark duality can be split into two parts.  The first part is Gelfand-Neumark duality proper and asserts a contravariant equivalence between the categories of commutative C*-algebras and compact regular locales.  It can be proved in any elementary topos, in particular the proof is constructive: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/constructive+Gelfand+duality+theorem.

Comment: The second part asserts that compact regular locales are spatial, in particular the category of compact regular locales is equivalent to the category of compact Hausdorff topological spaces.  This statement is equivalent to a weak form of the axiom of choice.  Your question belongs to the second part, but the connection to Gelfand-Neumark duality seems to be rather weak.

Comment: However, perhaps this example will do.  Consider a locally compact abelian group G and some character χ.  Integrating with respect to χ gives you a multiplicative functional (with respect to the convolution of functions, not the usual multiplication).  On the first glance it is unclear why this functional is evaluation at some point.  This is only revealed by the Fourier transform.

Comment: (@DP, Why not to post as an answer something wich *is* an answer?)

Comment: @Qfwfq: I have doubts whether my comment can be seen as an answer.  In particular, conditions (2) and (3) are rather vague and I am not sure how to interpret them.  Let's see what Martin has to say.

Comment: What is unclear about 2) and 3)? I agree with Qfwfq, please post an elaborate version of this as an answer, it sounds interesting. I don't know what it means to integrate with respect to a character. In any case it would be interesting to give a specific G and χ instead of another general Theorem. 

Comment: @Martin, this is not quite what you were asking, but one use (for me at least) of the point evaluation mindset is when one considers $C^\ast$-subalgebras of $C_b(X)$ where $X$ is *locally* compact. In the case where $X$ is a locally compact group, such algebras can arise in harmonic analysis, and then it can be useful to think of them as $C(Y)$ where $Y$ is some kind of compactification of the original group -- roughly like thinking of "evaluate at a point of the Stone-Cech compactification" instead of "take a limit along an ultrafulter".

Comment: @Yemon: Isn't this rather B)?

Comment: @Martin: yes, but I tend to view A) as the restriction to an appropriate subcategory of the unit of the adjunction from topological spaces to compact Hausdorff ones, which is just the Stone-Cech compactification. I agree that my previous comment does not really give an answer to (A) as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $X$ that satisfies a zero-one law (i.e. $\mu$ takes only values $0,1$) and has $\mu(X) = 1$. Then 
$$F: C(X) \to \mathbb{R},\; f \mapsto \int_X f\; d \mu$$
defines a ring homomorphism.

I'm not sure, if there are not even examples for $(X, \mu)$ such that $F$ isn't an evalution (of course in this case $X$ can't be a Q-space). At least, there are such examples for Baire measures. [Edit: See "Added 2" for an affirmative answer]

**Added:** To give an example, let $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal and let $X := [0,\omega_1]$ be the set of all ordinals $0  \le \alpha\le\omega_1$ considered as topological space with the order topology. Then $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Futhermore, it can be shown that if $B$ is a Borel set, then 
$$\mu(B) := \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } B \textstyle \text{ has an unbounded, closed  subset of }  X \setminus \lbrace \omega_1 \rbrace \newline 0, \textstyle\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
defines a Borel measure on $X$ (cf. Halmos, Measure Theory, Exercise 52.10).

Since $\mu$ is zero on finite sets, it's obviously no Dirac measure.

**Added 2:** The example also shows that the integral operator for a $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$-valued Borel measure is in general no evaluation:

Let $X_0 := [0,\omega_1) \subseteq X$. Then $\mu_0 := \mu|X_0$ is a $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$-valued Borel measure on $X_0$ with $\mu_0(X_0) = 1$ and
$$F_0: C(X_0) \to \mathbb{R},\; f \mapsto \int_{X_0} f\; d\mu_0$$
is a ring homomorphism that is no evaluation.

For, let $x \in X_0$ and set $f(\alpha) := 1$ if $\alpha \le x$, $f(\alpha) := 0$ if $\alpha > x$. $f$ is continuous and since $\mu([\alpha_0+1,\omega_1)) = 1$, $f = 0$ almost everythere. Hence $F_0(f) = 0$ but $e_x(f) = f(x) = 1$. Consequently there is no $x \in X_0$ such that $F_0 = e_x$.

---

**Also note** that if $X$ is compact, then, by the Riesz representation theorem, the only non-zero Radon measures with values in $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ are the Dirac measures.

Comment: Can you give some specific example, especially where $\mu$ isn't a dirac measure?

Comment: Space $\mathbb N$, the zero-one finitely additive measure is an ultrafilter.  They define homomorphisms, and the "points" corresponding to them are the points of the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta \mathbb N$.  So: it is not an evaluation to start with, but then we "invent" the points to make it so.

Comment: As Ralph hints, when the space $X$ is not a Q-space (or, in other language, not realcompact) there is a *countably-additive* example of a zero-one Baire measure that is not fixed.  The set of such things constitutes $\upsilon X$, the Hewitt realcompactification of $X$.

Comment: Ok, but isn't this just a fancy way to state the old result that prime ideals of a product of fields, indexed by a set $N$, correspond to ultrafilters on $N$?

Comment: @Ralph: Thanks for the update! Do we have $F(f)=f(\omega_1)$ in your example?

Comment: Is this the confirmation that the example satisfies "some computation has to be done to find the point $x\in X$ such that $F$ is the evaluation at $x$ ?"  -:) 

Comment: Hehe, indeed! I like this example.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a locally compact abelian group G and some character χ: G→**T**.
The functional M<sub>χ</sub>: f∈L<sub>1</sub>(G)↦∫fχ∈**C** is multiplicative: M<sub>χ</sub>(f*g)=M<sub>χ</sub>(f)M<sub>χ</sub>(g), where
f*g is the convolution of f and g.
At the first glance it is unclear why this functional should be given by the evaluation at some point.
However, Pontryagin duality tells us that the Fourier tranform f↦(χ∈Hom(G,**T**)↦M<sub>χ</sub>(f)∈**C**)
(with the appropriate domain and codomain)
is an isomorphism of algebras, where the first algebra structure is given by the convolution
and the second algebra structure is given by the pointwise multiplication.

The easiest concrete example is G=**T**, whose Pontryagin dual is **Z**,
and χ=id<sub>G</sub>, or perhaps even χ=1.

Comment: As someone who learned about Banach algebras before learning about Pontryagin duality, my way of looking at this would be that the Gelfand transform and associated theory gives us the canonical homomorphism $L^1(G) \to C_0(\Omega)$ for suitable $\Omega$, and then some analysis will be required to show that this homomorphism is injective. Is that what you are saying, or have I misunderstood? The power of the Gelfand representation is that it tells us we can view any non-zero multiplicative linear functional on a commutative (Banach) algebra as point evaluation, in a natural (pun intended) way

Comment: @Yemon: This is correct, but what do you mean by “some analysis”?  I have always thought that you only need Stone-Weierstraß to prove Gelfand-Neumark theorem for commutative C*-algebras.

Comment: You claim that the integral $L^1(G) \to \mathbb{C}$ is some evaluation?

Comment: Besides, my question asks about $C(X)$.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, the integral is an evaluation.

Comment: @Martin: The group C*-algebra of G is canonically isomorphic to C(X), where X is the Pontryagin dual of G.

Comment: @Martin: Or in other words, to define a functional on C(X) compose the inverse Fourier transform with M_χ.

Comment: @Dmitri: for a given commutative Banach algebra, one may need to do some work to show that the Gelfand representation is faithful. For a commutative B*-algebra (defined as an abstract algebra, not presuming the GN-theorem) I think this is not too hard, but for something like $L^1(T)$ you in effect need the fact that an integrable function whose Fourier coefficients are all zero is itself zero, and that is usually deduced from something like FEjer's theorem

Comment: @Yemon: No, the injectivity follows immediately from the formula for the spectral radius.  Also, L_1(T) is a commutative B*-algebra, so your own comment (“not too hard”) applies.

Comment: @Dmitri, I mean commutative $B^\ast$-algebra in the old original sense of Rickart et al: a normed $\ast$-algebra whose norm satisfies the $C^\ast$-identity. In other words, what is nowadays called an abstract $C^\ast$-algebra. In particular, $L^1(T)$ is MOST DEFINITELY NOT a B*-algebra in this sense. For $B^*$-algebras the injectivity of the Gelfand representation is not hard to prove, but you do need the $C^*$-condition and the fact that $b$ commutes with $b^*$ for each elements (thus commutative closed subalgebras of B(H) need not be remotely as nice as selfadjoint commutative subalgebras)

Comment: As I'm sure you know, general commutative Banach algebras need be nowhere near as nice as commutative $C*$-algebras. That was really all I was getting at.

Comment: I guess the mention of $L^1(G)$ is superfluous, what you are doing is taking a character of $G$ and saying that it gives you a nonzero multiplicative linear functional on the full group C*-algebra $C^*(G)$, via the universal property of the full group $C^*$-algebra construction. Then GN-duality kicks in, to say that this functional can be viewed naturally as point evaluation. But since you started with an element of $\widehat{G}$, rather than discovering it from the functional $C^*(G)\to C$, this doesn't seem quite what Martin was asking for.

Comment: @Yemon: The multiplicative functional under consideration is the composition of the inverse Fourier transform and the integration with respect to (the conjugate of) the function χ: G→T.  It is a nontrivial fact that this functional is given by the evaluation at some point (namely, χ regarded as an element of the Pontryagin dual).